# Why is "cum" used in this sentence from "De Bello Gallico"?

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunction, accusativus-cum-infinitivo, gaius-iulius-caesar

This sentence comes from Caesar's *De Bello Gallico* (emphasis mine in the part I'm trying to understand):

> Dum haec a Caesare geruntur, Treveri magnis coactis peditatus equitatusque copiis Labienum cum una legione, quae in eorum finibus hiemaverat, adoriri parabant, iamque ab eo non longius bidui via aberant, **cum duas venisse legiones** missu Caesaris cognoscunt.

In the expression *cum duas venisse legiones*, I find an accusative *duas legiones* and a perfect infinitive, *venisse*, so I suppose it's an  *accusativus cum infinitivo* construction. My problem is that I've never encountered such structure used with *cum*. What's the role of *cum* in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a temporal *cum* clause. See [section 545 in Allen and Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/cum-clauses).

*longius bidui...aberant cum ... cognoscunt.* ("they where not farther away than two days journey... **when** they noticed that ...)

*Cum* can indicate something alongside something else either in space or in time. Here, *cum* conjunctively indicates that the action of the final clause happened at the same time that they were two days away from wherever.

Comment: I see... So, in some sense, *cum* introduces the verb *cognoscunt* and has nothing to do with the *accusativus cum infinitivo*.

Comment: @Charo Right, it is simply a conjunction like the English "when" is used conjunctively.